# Eliminar un elemento de un array de objetos

Tags: java, array, poo

Tengo problemas a la hora de eliminar un elemento de un array de objetos. El código que tengo seria el siguiente:

```
private Plataforma[] plataformas;
public void eliminarPlataforma(String nombrePlataformaEliminar, int nClientes) {
    //Buscar posicion de la plataforma a eliminar
    for(int i=0; i<plataformas.length; i++) {
        if(plataformas[i].getNombre() == nombrePlataformaEliminar) {
            //Eliminar ese elemento
        }
    }
}
```

¿Cómo se eliminaría ese elemento?

Remarcar que no puedo importar nada mas que `java.util.Arrays`.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay que tener presente lo siguiente sobre los Arrays o arreglos en java

VENTAJAS

- Acceso y operación con elementos más eficiente.
- Permiten almacenar tanto objetos como tipos primitivos directamente

INCONVENIENTES

- Rigidez. No se pueden redimensionar (aunque sí copiar a otros arrays estáticos de mayor tamaño).

Esto indica que no se puede eliminar el espacio ya creado en el array por lo que deberas reemplazarlo por otro dato un *null* por ejemplo

otro dato es que el operador `==` que opera trabajando con las direcciones. Compara internamente las referencias de los objetos. Por otro lado, el método `equals` compara el contenido real de las instancias.
por lo que deberás usar el método `equals` para comparar correctamente los datos

```
for(int i=0; i<plataformas.length; i++) {
        if(plataformas[i].getNombre().equals(nombrePlataformaEliminar)) {
            plataformas[i]=null;//reemplazas el valor
        }
```

si lo que buscas es redimensionar el array obteniendo los valores diferentes de `null` en un nuevo array podes usar el metodo `filter`

```
Plataforma [] nuevoArraySinNull=Arrays.stream(plataformas).filter(p->p!=null).toArray(Plataforma[]::new);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. De todas formas creando otro array algo tipo  Plataforma[] nuevoArray= new Plataforma[plataformas.length -1]; , como podria meter ahi todos los datos nuevos sin dejar una posicion con un null?

Comment: poder  iterar el primer array que contiene null y con una condicional `if(plataformar[i]!=null)` si es diferente de null agregar al nuevo array

Comment: Muchas gracias. Problema resuelto :)

Comment: @RobertoMoralesfumero si la respuesta te fue  útil , podes marcar el check-in ✓, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema lo tienes aquí:

```
if(plataformas[i].getNombre() == nombrePlataformaEliminar) {
    //Eliminar ese elemento
}
```

En java no puedes comparar *strings* de una una forma directa, tienes que usar el método *equals*: `String1.equals(String2)`. Usar el operador == compara si las instancias son la misma, ya que los *Strings* no son tipos primitivos de datos. El código sería algo así:

```
if(plataformas[i].getNombre().equals(nombrePlataformaEliminar)) {
    plataformas[i]=null; //lo conviertes a null
}
```